# SYSTEM-DIALOG GET-FILE with dynamic file type filters

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

Using OpenEdge 11.7 and Windows 7, I'm searching for a disk file using this working code:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFileName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lChose AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

SYSTEM-DIALOG GET-FILE cFileName
    FILTERS "Text Files (*.txt)" "*.txt", "Comma-Separated Value Files (*.csv)" "*.csv"
    UPDATE lChose.
```

Is there a way to dynamically build the filter list with a variable? I've tried this, which doesn't work:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFileName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFilters AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lChose AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

cFilters = '"Text Files (*.txt)" "*.txt", "Comma-Separated Value Files (*.csv)" "*.csv"'.

SYSTEM-DIALOG GET-FILE cFileName
    FILTERS cFilters
    UPDATE lChose.
```

I've also tried:

```
FILTERS VALUE(cFilters)
```

Both return an "unable to understand" error (198). Can this even be done?

Comment: Here's the docs for the command: https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/system-dialog-get-file-statement.html

This suggests that what you want isn't possible. I can't say I've ever seen it done either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABL and it's funny syntax ... the documentation states that every filter label and filter filespec is an expression by itself. You can pass empty pairs, those will be ignored. So this here works - array elements 5 - 10 are empty and surpressed:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFileName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFilters AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO EXTENT 10.
DEFINE VARIABLE lChose AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN 
    cFilters[1] = "Text Files (*.txt)" 
    cFilters[2] = "*.txt"
    cFilters[3] = "Comma-Separated Value Files (*.csv)"
    cFilters[4] = "*.csv" .

SYSTEM-DIALOG GET-FILE cFileName
    FILTERS cFilters[1] cFilters[2], cFilters[3] cFilters[4], cFilters[5] cFilters[6], cFilters[7] cFilters[8], cFilters[9] cFilters[10]   
    UPDATE lChose.
```

Or use .NET as an alternative:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFileName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFilters AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lChose AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

cFilters = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|Comma-Separated Value Files (*.csv)|*.csv".

DEFINE VARIABLE oSystemDialog AS System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog NO-UNDO . 
DEFINE VARIABLE oDialogResult AS System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult NO-UNDO . 

oSystemDialog = NEW System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog () .
oSystemDialog:Filter = cFilters .
oSystemDialog:CheckFileExists = TRUE . 
oSystemDialog:RestoreDirectory  = TRUE .

WAIT-FOR oSystemDialog:ShowDialog () SET oDialogResult . 

IF Progress.Util.EnumHelper:AreEqual (oDialogResult, System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult:OK) THEN
DO:
    ASSIGN lChose = TRUE 
           cFileName = oSystemDialog:FileName. 
END.
ELSE 
    ASSIGN lChose = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is possible to write

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFileName AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFilter1a AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFilter1b AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFilter2a AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFilter2b AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lChoose AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

assign
    cFilter1a = "Text Files (*.txt)"
    cFilter1b = "*.txt"
    cFilter2a = "Comma-Separated Value Files (*.csv)"
    cFilter2b = "*.csv"
.

SYSTEM-DIALOG GET-FILE cFileName
    FILTERS cFilter1a cFilter1b, cFilter2a cFilter2b
    UPDATE lChoose.
```

which might or might not be useful for you.